# Julia - last() does not work inside the function

Tags: julia

I am writing the below code, and in the code the last() function does not work. I get the below error.

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: last not defined
```

But when I use last() outside of the function with same logic it works.

I am trying to write the below function -

```
function mergeOverlappingIntervals(intervals)
    sort!(intervals, by = x -> intervals[1])
    new_interval = intervals[1]
    for i in range(2, length(intervals))
        if last(new_intervals)[2] >= intervals[i][1]
            last(new_intervals) = [minimum!(last(new_intervals)[1], intervals[i][1]), maximum!(last(new_intervals)[2], intervals[2])]
        else
            push!(new_interval, intervals[i])
        end
    end
end
```

Can you please help?

Comment: `new_intervals` is not defined?

Comment: Yes, the interval should be a vector like this [[1, 2], [3,5], [4,6]]

Comment: changes 'new_intervals' to 'new_interval' - still code is giving the same error. The error I am getting is 'UndefVarError': last not defined

Comment: Are you supposed to get the output [[1, 2], [3, 6]] from  [[1, 2], [3,5], [4,6]] if the function is working?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to merge the intervals, note that your sort does not work since `by = x -> intervals[1] is a constant: you wanted to say by = x -> x[1]. and the default sort on vectors does that already.

You could instead do:

```
using Random

intervals = shuffle([[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6]])

function mergeintervals(intervals)
    @assert length(intervals) > 1
    sort!(intervals)
    a = [copy(intervals[begin])]
    for v in @view intervals[begin+1:end]
        if a[end][end] >= v[begin]
            if a[end][end] < v[end]
                a[end][end] = v[end]
            end
        else
            push!(a, copy(v))
        end
    end
    return a
end

@show mergeintervals(intervals) # [[1, 2], [3, 6]]
```

The reason last(x) does not work is that (unlike x[end]) it does not  return  an `lvalue`,  that is, it does not produce a value or syntactic expression that you can assign to. So Julia thinks you are trying to redefine the function last(x) when you attempt to assign to it (as DNF pointed out). (An `lvalue` is something that can be used as the left hand side of an assignment, which in Julia does not mean it is a direct memory address: see below).

Comment: `x[i] = a` actually isn't an assignment at all, but syntactic sugar for `setindex!(x, i, a)`. And `f(x) =... ` is function definition syntax, not assignment. In Julia, you cannot assign to a value at all, only to a variable.

Comment: So, the left side of `last(x) =... ` and `x[i] =... ` not just don't produce an lvalue, they produce no value at all, they aren't even evaluated, as such. They are not function call followed by assignment, or vector access followed by assignment, they are syntactic sugar that get transformed into something completely different. It's maybe a bit confusing.

Comment: I added your indexing is indirect, not direct memory access caveat to the note.

Comment: Actually, the whole lvalue thing is not really the point. In Julia you cannot assign to values, only to variables. A variable is not a value, it is a symbol that is bound to a value. This is distinct from e.g. C++, where you _can_ assign to values, so the question of lvalues are meaningful. Here's a blog post on the subject that many people like: https://www.juliabloggers.com/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory-3/

Comment: And `last(x)` is no different from `x[end]` in this regard, you cannot assign to the return value of `x[end]`. It just *looks like* you can, because `x[end] = val` works. But that is because the compiler tricks you, because `x[end] = val` is transformed to `setindex!(x, lastindex(x), val)` during _lowering_. It isn't assignment at all. You can try: `x0 = x[end]; x0 = val` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward implementation, after fixing two errors. `last()` cannot be assigned to as others said, and `minimum` or `maximum` are used with arrays, you want `max` here to compare scalars. Finally you should return the new merged stack of intervals.

```
function mergeIntervals(intervals)
    sort!(intervals)
    stack = [intervals[1]]
    for i in 2:length(intervals)
        if stack[end][2] < intervals[i][1]
            push!(stack, intervals[i])
        else
            stack[end][2] = max(stack[end][2], intervals[i][2])
        end
    end
    return stack
end
```

Test an example:

```
intervals = [[6, 8], [1, 9], [2, 4], [4, 7]]
mergeIntervals(intervals) 
[[1, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by taking the suggestions from all the answers posted. Thank you.

Below is the code -

```
function mergeOverlappingIntervals(intervals)
    sort!(intervals, by = x -> intervals[1])
    new_interval = [intervals[1]]
    for i in range(2, length(intervals))
        if new_interval[end][2] >= intervals[i][1]
            new_interval[end] = [min(new_interval[end][1], intervals[i][1]), max(new_interval[end][2], intervals[i][2])]
        else
            push!(new_interval, intervals[i])
        end
    end
    return new_interval
end
```